# Is it possible to disable "retry" from bounce mails in postfix?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, configuration, email-bounces

I am doing mass BCC email's for mailing list, and receive too many bounces, Is there a way to stop it from retrying?

I have been searching around and can't seem to find the answer, if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disable bouncing by commenting out "bounce..." line in etc/postfix/master.cf

Comment: No such thing, only can find soft_bounce, which is opposite of what I want.

Comment: Sorry, i ment /etc/postfix/master.cf